A different generation of trees for every player. multiplayer (netcode for gameObjects)
When 2 or more players connect to each other, the trees are generated slightly differently for each player.
I tried to add Network transform to the prefab tree, but it didn't help and it's still different
Host's pov:

Client's pov:

This is script that generate terrain(mesh) and trees (DataStorage is a class that stores data between scenes):
using UnityEngine;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using Unity.Netcode;

public class MeshGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
    Mesh mesh;

    Vector3[] vertices;
    int[] triangles;

    [Header("Map settings")]
    public int Size = 20;

    [Space]

    public float heightMultiplier = 20f;

    public AnimationCurve curve;  

    [Header("Noise map")]
    public float scale = 0.3f;

    public int octaves;
    public float presistance;
    public float lacunarity;

    [Space]

    public int seed;
    public Vector2 offset;

    float[,] heightMap;

    [Header("Trees")]
    public GameObject treePrefab;

    [Space]

    public int PosibleTrees;
    public int trees;

    float[,] treeHeightMap;



    [Header("Texture")]
    public Material mat;

    [Space]

    public Layer[] layers;

    const int textureSize = 512;
    const TextureFormat textureFormat = TextureFormat.RGB565;

    Vector2[] uvs;

    [Header("Player")]

    public GameObject playerPrefab;

    bool multiplayer;
    bool client;

    System.Random seedGen;

    async void Awake()
    {
        mesh = new Mesh();
        GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = mesh;
        mesh.name = "Mesh";

        heightMap = GenerateNoiseMap(Size, scale, seed, octaves, presistance, lacunarity, offset);
        treeHeightMap = GenerateNoiseMap(Size, scale, seed + 3, octaves, presistance, lacunarity, offset);
        seed = DataStorage.seed;
        multiplayer = DataStorage.multiplayer;
        client = DataStorage.client;

        seedGen = new System.Random(seed);

        await Task.Delay(1000);

        CreateShape();
        UpdateMesh();
     
        LevelManager.instance._loaderConvas.SetActive(false);

    }

    void CreateShape()
    {

        vertices = new Vector3[(Size + 1) * (Size + 1)];


        for (int i = 0, z = 0; z <= Size; z++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x <= Size; x++)
            {

                float currentHeight = (float)curve.Evaluate((float)heightMap[x, z]) * (float)heightMultiplier;

                GenerateTree(currentHeight, x, z, seedGen);

                vertices[i] = new Vector3(x, currentHeight, z);
                i++;
            }
        }

        triangles = new int[Size * Size * 6];

        int vert = 0;
        int tris = 0;

        for (int z = 0; z < Size; z++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < Size; x++)
            {
                triangles[tris + 0] = vert + 0;
                triangles[tris + 1] = vert + Size + 1;
                triangles[tris + 2] = vert + 1;
                triangles[tris + 3] = vert + 1;
                triangles[tris + 4] = vert + Size + 1;
                triangles[tris + 5] = vert + Size + 2;

                vert++;
                tris += 6;
            }
            vert++;
        }

        GenerateUVs();

        SetShaderVariable();
    }

    void GenerateUVs()
    {
        uvs = new Vector2[vertices.Length];
        for (int i = 0, z = 0; z <= Size; z++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x <= Size; x++)
            {
                uvs[i] = new Vector2((float)x / Size, (float)z / Size);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    void SetShaderVariable()
    {
        mat.SetFloat("minHeight", heightMultiplier * curve.Evaluate(0));
        mat.SetFloat("maxHeight", heightMultiplier * curve.Evaluate(1));

        mat.SetInt("layerCount", layers.Length);
        mat.SetColorArray("baseColours", layers.Select(x => x.tint).ToArray());
        mat.SetFloatArray("baseStartHeights", layers.Select(x => x.startHeigth).ToArray());
        mat.SetFloatArray("baseBlends", layers.Select(x => x.blendStrength).ToArray());
        mat.SetFloatArray("baseColourStrength", layers.Select(x => x.tintStrength).ToArray());
        mat.SetFloatArray("baseTextureScales", layers.Select(x => x.textureScale).ToArray());

        Texture2DArray textureArray = GenerateTextureArray(layers.Select(x => x.texture).ToArray());

        mat.SetTexture("baseTextures", textureArray);
    }

    void SpawnPlayer(float currentHeight, Vector3 pos)
    {
        GameObject player = Instantiate(playerPrefab);

        player.transform.position = pos;
    }

    Texture2DArray GenerateTextureArray(Texture2D[] textures)
    {
        Texture2DArray textureArray = new Texture2DArray(textureSize, textureSize, textures.Length, textureFormat, true);

        for(int i = 0; i < textures.Length; i++)
        {
            textureArray.SetPixels(textures[i].GetPixels(), i);
        }

        textureArray.Apply();

        return textureArray;
    }
    void UpdateMesh()
    {
        mesh.Clear();

        mesh.vertices = vertices;
        mesh.triangles = triangles;
        mesh.uv = uvs;

        mesh.RecalculateNormals();

        GetComponent<MeshCollider>().sharedMesh = mesh;

        float currentHeight;
        Vector3 pos;

        while (true)
        {
            int x = seedGen.Next(0, Size);
            int z = seedGen.Next(0, Size);

            currentHeight = (float)curve.Evaluate((float)heightMap[x, z]) * (float)heightMultiplier;

            if (currentHeight > 1.8)
            {
                pos = new Vector3(x, (float)currentHeight + 2f, z);
                break;
            }
        }



     

        if (multiplayer && !client)
        {
            DataStorage.x = (float)pos.x;
            DataStorage.y = (float)pos.y;
            DataStorage.z = (float)pos.z;

            if (NetworkManager.Singleton.StartHost())
            {
                Debug.Log("host");
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("host failed");
            }
        }
        else if (DataStorage.solo == true)
        {
            SpawnPlayer(currentHeight, pos);
            Debug.Log("player");
        }
    }

    float[,] GenerateNoiseMap(int size, float scale, int seed, int octaves, float presistance, float lacunarity, Vector2 offset)
    {
        float[,] noiseMap = new float[size + 1, size + 1];

        System.Random prng = new System.Random(seed);
        Vector2[] octaveOffsets = new Vector2[octaves + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i <= octaves; i++)
        {
            float offsetX = prng.Next(-100000, 100000) + offset.x;
            float offsetZ = prng.Next(-100000, 100000) + offset.y;

            octaveOffsets[i] = new Vector2(offsetX, offsetZ);
        }

        if (scale <= 0)
        {
            scale = 0.0001f;
        }

        float minNoiseHeight = float.MaxValue;
        float maxNoiseHeight = float.MinValue;

        float halfSize = size / 2;

        for (int z = 0; z <= size; z++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x <= size; x++)
            {

                float amplitude = 1;
                float frequency = 1;
                float noiseHeight = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i <= octaves; i++)
                {
                    float sampleX = (x - halfSize) / scale * frequency + octaveOffsets[i].x;
                    float sampleY = (z - halfSize) / scale * frequency + octaveOffsets[i].y;

                    float perlinValue = Mathf.PerlinNoise(sampleX, sampleY) * 2 - 1;
                    noiseHeight += perlinValue * amplitude;

                    amplitude *= presistance;
                    frequency *= lacunarity;
                }

                if (noiseHeight < minNoiseHeight)
                {
                    minNoiseHeight = noiseHeight;
                }
                else if (noiseHeight > maxNoiseHeight)
                {
                    maxNoiseHeight = noiseHeight;
                }

                noiseMap[x, z] = noiseHeight;
            }
        }

        for (int z = 0; z <= size; z++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x <= size; x++)
            {
                noiseMap[x, z] = Mathf.InverseLerp(minNoiseHeight, maxNoiseHeight, noiseMap[x, z]);

                float fallOffX = z / (float)size * 2 - 1;
                float fallOffZ = x / (float)size * 2 - 1;

                float value = Mathf.Max(Mathf.Abs(fallOffX), Mathf.Abs(fallOffZ));

                noiseMap[x, z] = Mathf.Clamp01(noiseMap[x, z] - Evaluate(value));
            }
        }

        return noiseMap;
    }

    void GenerateTree(float currentHeight, int x, int z, System.Random prng)
    {

        PosibleTrees++;

        int d = prng.Next(0, 10);
        int c = prng.Next(0, 10);

        double X = prng.NextDouble();
        double Z = prng.NextDouble();
        double Y = prng.NextDouble();

        if(Y < .5f)
        {
            Y = .5f;
        }

        if (treeHeightMap[x, z] >= Y && currentHeight > 1.5 && currentHeight < 10 && d >= 8)
        {
            GameObject tree = Instantiate(treePrefab);

            tree.transform.position = new Vector3((float)(x + X), currentHeight, (float)(z + Z));

            trees++;
        }
    }

    float Evaluate(float value)
    {
        float a = 3;
        float b = 2.2f;

        return Mathf.Pow(value, a) / (Mathf.Pow(value, a) + Mathf.Pow(b - b * value, a));
    }


    [System.Serializable]
    public class Layer
    {
        public Texture2D texture;
        public Color tint;

        [Range(0,1)]
        public float tintStrength;

        [Range(0, 1)]
        public float startHeigth;

        [Range(0, 1)]
        public float blendStrength;

        public float textureScale;
    }

    /*private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.black;
        for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i++)
        {
            Gizmos.DrawSphere(vertices[i], 0.1f);
        }
    }*/
}

This is a script that is attached to a tree to prevent trees from flying in the air (There may be a collision problem, so they will be destroyed, but but if that's the case, I don't know how to fix it.):
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.VisualScripting.Antlr3.Runtime.Tree;
using UnityEngine;

public class TreeMnager : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject groundCheck;
    public GameObject iTree;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        if(!Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.transform.position, .1f, LayerMask.GetMask("Mesh")))
        {
            Destroy(iTree);
        }

        Collider[] hitColliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(iTree.transform.position, 1);
        foreach (var hitCollider in hitColliders)
        {
            if (hitCollider.gameObject != iTree &&
                hitCollider.gameObject.CompareTag("Tree"))
            {
                Destroy(iTree);
            }
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}

This script controls what type of game will be played(Multyplayer/singleplayer):
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Unity.Netcode;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class LevelManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static LevelManager instance;

    public GameObject _loaderConvas;
    [SerializeField] private Slider _loaderSlider;
    [SerializeField] private InputField input;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Awake()
    {
        if(instance == null)
        {
            instance = this;
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        }
        else
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

    public async void LoadScene(string sceneName)
    {
        int seed = 0;
        int.TryParse(input.text, out seed);

        if(seed == 0)
        {
            seed = Random.Range(-2147483647, 2147483647);
        }

        DataStorage.seed = seed;
        DataStorage.multiplayer = false;
        DataStorage.client = false;
        DataStorage.solo = true;

        var scene = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(sceneName);
        scene.allowSceneActivation = false;

       _loaderConvas.SetActive(true);

        do
        {
            await Task.Delay(500);
            _loaderSlider.value = scene.progress;
        } while (scene.progress < 0.9f);

        scene.allowSceneActivation = true;
    }

    public async void LoadSceneHost(string sceneName)
    {
        int seed = 0;
        int.TryParse(input.text, out seed);

        if (seed == 0)
        {
            seed = Random.Range(-2147483647, 2147483647);
        }

        DataStorage.seed = seed;
        DataStorage.multiplayer = true;
        DataStorage.client = false;
        DataStorage.solo = false;

        var scene = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(sceneName);
        scene.allowSceneActivation = false;

        _loaderConvas.SetActive(true);

        do
        {
            await Task.Delay(500);
            _loaderSlider.value = scene.progress;
        } while (scene.progress < 0.9f);

        scene.allowSceneActivation = true;
    }

    public void JoinWorld()
    {

        DataStorage.multiplayer = true;
        DataStorage.client = true;
        DataStorage.solo = false;

        if (NetworkManager.Singleton.StartClient())
        {
            Debug.Log("succes");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("World not found");
        }
    }
}


well who generates the trees? if they each generate their own trees why would they be the same?

Well, the terrain is the same, just not the trees, but it's true that I don't send seed, so the trees can be generated by other seed, but in that case the terrain should be different too, right?

@Jonda_MC we can not tell without seeing your code tbh

Later I can add script that starts the "session", but am not home right now.

@derHugo , I've added all the scripts that could be causing this bad generation.

Is this C# or UnityScript?

@TylerH It's C#

You do
heightMap = GenerateNoiseMap(Size, scale, seed, octaves, presistance, lacunarity, offset);
treeHeightMap = GenerateNoiseMap(Size, scale, seed + 3, octaves, presistance, lacunarity, offset);

which both already use seed right before you even assign it to
seed = DataStorage.seed;

So later the CreateShape and finally GenerateTree etc definitely use a different
seedGen = new System.Random(seed);

than the height map generations before.
=> You probably want to move this on top so everything actually uses the very same seed.

I know: This still does not explain why they are different between host and client. But fixing this first issue might spread some more light on that

Thanks, I hadn't noticed that at all. But now it makes sense, because on the client I'm now generating a world with seed 0 (because DataStorage.seed is not set and so it's 0), so I just need to get the seed to the client somehow, do you know how to do it?

when I set in script seed to 0 to host, it looks same, but I think there is a difference between singleplayer and multiplayer, but I wouldn't worry about it
